# How to pass text from form to javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, symfony

So I have little problem, I want to write something in form and pass it to symfony2 controller, but I have no idea how can I do it. I tried something like this:

Index.html:

```
<form action='#close' ng-submit='calCtrl.test(day.id, $index)'>
<div class='form-field'>
<span class='sp'>Podaj opis (opcjonalnie):</span><br />
        <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div class='form-field'>
        <input type='submit' value='Zmień'>
</div>
</form>
```

Controllers.js:

```
this.test = function($id, $index) {
        $http.put('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/notes/' + $id + '.json');
};
```

Symfony controller:

```
public function putNoteAction(Request $request, $id) { 
}
```

Now I can pass only $id and nothing more.

Comment: to submit data, you must specify it at `name` and `value` attributes for div/span/etc.. there is especially `<input type=hidden name="mydata" value="myvalue" />`

Comment: Which type of data do you want to pass ? Is your form manually written or generated from a Symfony form ?

Comment: This, which I wrote here is manually. And I want to pass string.

Answer (score 0):

To get value from form to javascript function, you can do as follows:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunc()">
<input type="text" id="t1">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunc()
{
  alert(document.getElementById("t1").value);
}
</script>
```

Furthermore, if the form is submitting value to server side, then still at server end you can assign the values to javascript variables. like:

```
<form action="action.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" id="t1" name="t1">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

action.php code will be as follows:-

```
// To assign form posted value to javascript variable. 
 var javascript_variable = <?php echo $_GET['t1']; ?>;
```

You can use same approach with symfony using symfony syntax..